# How to add wsdl client code to ejb project?

Tags: eclipse, wsdl, ejb

I want to add wsdl client code to ejb project and then call it somehow. But I can't. This is how I do:

**File>New project> Web Serbice Client>**

But I can not see my ejb project in "Client project" combo box. What is wrong? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create stub code in any project from list in the right side of the screenshot, and then move it to your EJB project, then adapt packages names and etc. But why you are going to call webservice from Enterprise bean? Why you are not going to use Remote EJB call for this purpose?